# Receber e tratar JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Boa noite pessoal, sou novo no mundo da programação,estou recebendo uma informação de um webservice  via json, e agora estou precisando manipular as  informações desse json, por exemplo, gostaria de pegar apenas o [nome], alguem poderia me dar um  norte. Desde já agradeço.

```
//Recebendo o Json
$dados= json_decode($response);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dados);
echo "</pre>";

// Dados Exibidos
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uuid] => 8ec4e4c4d6c78a7ab7692c410448a5b7ebcb3bad
                    [nome] => TESTANDOAPI2
                    [slug] => testandoapi2
                    [created] => 2018-10-15 13:06:16
                    [total] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uuid] => aa02900bff1081c1a12d998e9a15d6c01845af84
                    [nome] => TESTANDOAPI
                    [slug] => testandoapi
                    [created] => 2018-10-15 12:53:05
                    [total] => 0
                )

        )

    [total] => 2
)
```

> Estou utilizando PHP para receber os dados, preciso tratar a resposta e exibir na tela.

Comment: Tudo bem que você está utilizando JSON como objeto, mas em qual linguagem você está programando para tentar manipular o objeto? Pelo `print_r` imagino que PHP, correto? Caso positivo faça edições para deixar mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

Deduzindo pelo `print_r` que seja PHP que você está utilizando para obter o objeto JSON...

Esta questão foi respondida no Stack em Inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url

#### Apenas traduzindo:

```
$obj = json_decode($result); // resultado da sua requisição
echo $obj->nome; // atributo do objeto que deseja obter
```

Comment: Como sua resposta é um array, você deve iterar em um foreach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: É um array composto por dois objetos, e cada objeto tem uma 10 atributos, mesmo assim posso suar o foreach?

Comment: Estou deduzindo que sim com base em meu conhecimento com Angular. No caso como sua resposta é `data[0]; data[1]...` e os atributos estão dentro de `data[i]`, ou seja, não haverá problemas, pelo que entendi.